# GitEye - No Repository Selected

Tags: git, repository, giteye

I get "No Repository Selected". But how to select a repository? I already googled it, but did not found the solution. I already searched the whole GitEye UI but it seems that there is no possibility to select a repository.

Comment: Im not sure how, but now there is a repository selected again. To select a repository, you just have to click on a folder on the left. But this did not worked for me, i removed a .project file and restarted GitEye, now it works again...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Many people claim that "Enabling linking between the Git Staging view and other views" solved their issue. Please refer to this [post on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30992337/how-to-select-repository-for-staging-view-in-eclipse-luna-4-4/).

"Enabling linking between the Git Staging view and other views" didn't help in my case. I also tried deleting branch and checking out again. Nothing worked.

What I did was:

*Right click on any of the modified file -> Team -> Commit.*

Somehow it worked and I could see all modified files in unstaged changes.

Answer (score 1):

I enabled the button "Link with Editor and Selection", and selected my repo.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Just enabling "Link with editor and selection" alone (as proposed in other answers) did not help me immediately. But after I simply closed and re-started the application, the message "No Repository Selected" turned into "Synchronizing with {repository name}" and I got the view that I expected.